# Accessing container running on bridge network from secondary port of host PC

Tags: docker, containers

I have Linux Debian PC with two Network interfaces: X1 & X2

Port X1 has IP : 132.186.90.12

Port X2 has IP : 172.17.0.111

I Created a bridge network  to have its own network for conatainers using following command in this Debian linux PC

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 mynet
```

Then i create container instances using following command

```
docker run --name container1 --rm -it -d --net=mynet mydockerimg
```

a container get created with IP 192.168.0.2 and broadcasts some data over port 4840

I am able to ping "192.168.0.2" from X1 sucessfully.

but a ping "192.168.0.2" from X2 fails, what could be the reason ?

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses are not useful in most cases; you don’t generally need to look them up or manually specify them.  They can’t be reached at all from other hosts, for example.  The `docker run -p` option will let you specify which host interface Docker should bind to for services that should be published.

Comment: how can you choose to ping specifically from an interface or another?

Comment: @Stefano I connected another PC to this port to check the ping from X2,  X1 is my primary interface

Comment: As @David Maze already pointed out, you should use the port to make the docker container visibile outside the host. The docker network is not a real network that you can access from outside. Moreover it's a private network, so the second machine wouldn't know the route on its own.

Comment: @Stefano can you please share code something on how to do it

Comment: any updates, still issue is not resolved